# Why do some words sound/feel more fake than others? Is there logic/psychology behind this phenomenon?

Tags: pronunciation, word-formation

I was recently reading Lewis Carroll's [Jabberwocky](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42916/jabberwocky) poem and had the thought that some of the made-up words sounded more real than some real words.

And looking at a [list of words](https://www.rd.com/list/funny-words-sound-fake/) that are real but are very strange, I find that some of them also feel more fake than others.

So what causes this feeling of a word being fake or real?

Note: some of the words on the real-but-fake-sounding list may or may not be in certain dictionaries. Merriam-Webster had [spondulicks](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spondulicks) and [firkin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firkin) but not [yemeles](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yemeles) nor [pronk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pronk). So I recognize that it's not a definitive list, but I'm using that list as a starting point.

Comment: It's highly individualistic. Since everybody learns their own language, they develop their own expectations of how things should sound and what they should mean. But no one ever learns the whole language, and it's always changing, so we encounter new odd things quite frequently. It's like weather; it's usually weird and unpredictable, but it's always there.